# Centos document_root default user and group

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

After default CentOs 5.5 install - Document_Root directory (/var/www/html) is owned by root.
In my httpd.conf file I have:

**user apache 
group apache**

mmm. Should I change ownership of /var/www/html to apache:apache?

**UPDATE**

Never mind. I was trying to figure out why I can't access a directory that i've created inside of the Document_Root. Then I've stoped SELinux and was able to access that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need not to change the ownership of `/var/ww/html` from root:root. But it should be in 755 permission.

What error you are getting while accessing the folder inside `/var/www/html`

Comment: TThe problem was in selinux as I finally figured:) thanks for ur answer anyway.